# Bookdown: Set Page Breaks

Tags: r, bookdown

I cannot find out how to make a page break in R bookdown.
With page break I mean that the content within one page is displayed as one website.

By default there is always a page break in front of every new section (like `# Chapter 1`).
So, if I run `render_book` each section becomes one html file.
But, if I have a lot of subsections then these sites get very long.

I would like to have page breaks before every subsection (like `## Chapter 1.1`).

So far I tried adding `\newpage`, `\pagebreak`, `---------------` to the .Rmd or to just provide the .Rmd files in the same structure as I would like to have them as .html files.
Either way, the .html files are always created according to the sections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is specified by the `split_by` argument of `gitbook` [as documented here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html).

Sounds like you are using `chapter` but you want to be using `section`

> The `split_by` argument specifies how you want to split the HTML output
>   into multiple pages, and its possible values are:
>
> - `rmd`: use the base filenames of the input Rmd files to create the HTML filenames, e.g., generate `chapter3.html` for `chapter3.Rmd`;
> - `none`: do not split the HTML file (the book will be a single HTML file);
> - `chapter`: split the file by the first-level headers;
> - `section`: split the file by the second-level headers;
> - `chapter+number` and `section+number`: similar to `chapter` and `section`, but the files will be numbered;

Comment: You can use it with `render_book()`. Output formats in bookdown are typically designed for `bookdown::render_book()`, and some also work with `rmarkdown::render()`. This answer applies to any output format function in bookdown that contains the `split_by` argument.

Comment: @Yihui that's good to know. I was surprised, the documentation of `render_book` doesn't mention the `split_by` argument, and even the `...` documentation is only for `preview_chapter`, nothing about what `render_book`'s `...` is passed on to.

Comment: The help page `?bookdown::render_book` said `...` was passed to `rmarkdown::render()`. `split_by` is not an argument of `bookdown::render_book()` or `rmarkdown::render()`; it is an argument of `bookdown::gitbook`.

Comment: I know this is long ago, but you can set it as option in `_output.yml`: `split_by: section` in the `bookdown::gitbook:` part.