# Bookdown: Is it possible to "split_by" at the subsection level?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I use the HTML and PDF outputs from bookdown as instructional material in a programming course, and I'd like to achieve the "page break" effect at the subsection level in addition to the chapter and section levels.

From what I have read in the bookdown documentation, "subsection" is not a permissible setting for the `split_by` argument in my bookdown's "_output.yaml" file.

`bookdown::gitbook:
  split_by: section`

Is there a workaround besides creating individual books for each chapter (thus turning my current book-level subsections into chapter-level sections)?  I strongly prefer having one book at the end.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick response, and thanks for making bookdown.

Answer (score 3):

A work around might be using "split_by: rmd"; see [this answer for reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39967034/2400133)
Then you put contents in each subsection into a separate Rmd file.

I tried this, and it works. The drawback is that I always receive this message when preview the book in Rstudio:

> In split_chapters(output, gitbook_page, number_sections, split_by,  : 
>   You have 5 Rmd input file(s) but only 3 first-level heading(s). Did
>   you forget first-level headings in certain Rmd files?

Also, I don't know if there are other drawbacks.